# Release pipeline - Helm Upgrade failure

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am using azure Devops for my CICD. I get the below error in release pipeline - Helm upgrade stage. I am not getting any clues as to what causes this. I am not able to go past this stage from the past one day. I do not know what is the "another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress"

Any help to resolve this would greatly be appreciated, thanks.

[image: Azure devops release pipeline]

Comment: Do you really need helm `3.0.0`. You have already `3.x.x` installed on both [Linux](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) and [Windows](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) agents. Please try without installing helm.

Comment: I disabled helm install stage - same result

Comment: Could you try running the `helm upgrade` command on your local machine to see if it works fine locally?

Comment: Can you try running the helm upgrade with --debug, hopefully that will give you more info.

Comment: What is the pre job helm upgrade? maybe it's still running?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I was able to solve it by running this command:

```
helm rollback <chart name>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while releasing using the ADO pipeline. Finally, I have figured it out using the below steps. I was not even able to list the release under this usual command.

`helm list -n <name-space>`

this was responding empty. So it's funny behavior from the helm.

`kubectl config get-contexts`

make sure your context is set for the correct Kubernetes cluster. Then next step is

`helm history <release> -n <name-space> --kube-context <kube-context-name>`

try applying the rollback to above command.

`helm rollback <release> <revision> -n <name-space> --kube-context <kube-context-nam>`

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve the issue using

```
helm delete <chart name>
```